# Is it possible to restore mac os image on a macbook after installing Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, macos

I would like to install Windows 10 on my Macbook Pro which is currently running MacOS Monterey. I do not have enough hard disk space to dual boot so I need to remove my present OS and install Windows instead. If, just in case, I would decide to go back to MacOS, would this be possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone, boot & restore a copy of your Mac's drive using something like
[Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com), or you could use Time Machine to restore.
Each has its caveats, so you need to be sure they will work before committing. Sensibly, this will need two external drives as backup.

Time Machine itself isn't perfect for this - it usually works but it *can* go wrong [with no explanation or fix] & leave you stranded, which is why you really need both.

Carbon Copy Cloner used to be absolutely perfect for this, but Apple has made the task harder in recent macOS versions, so read this blog first…
https://bombich.com/blog/2021/05/19/beyond-bootable-backups-adapting-recovery-strategies-evolving-platform